# Sharepoint workflow create task properties: when to create fields and when to create depepndency properties?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint workflows.

When creating a new task and assign the TaskId I have two options:

1. To create a new field to hold the TaskId
2. To create a new property to hold the TaskId.

The new property is a dependency property.

My question is what is the difference between assigning the task as a field or as a property?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my (short) experience, WF DP can be useful in two cases :

- you wan to split your workflow into subactivities, or you create custom activities. In this case, you have to use DP in order to pass data from the container to your activity in design mode (in code you can also with a public field).
- you want to enhance the design time experience and/or apply some validation. You can apply some validation rules, editors, description, etc. that can help the developer to correctly use the property.

hth